# Numpy: efficiently apply function that takes surrounding cells

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array (Potential) and I would like to compute the electromagnetic field. Right now it is the bottleneck of my program.

I have an array V dimension n+2, m+2. I want to create an Array E dimension n,m. The calculation of each cell is to do cell is ~:
sqrt((Cell_left-Cell_right)^2+(Cell_top-Cell_bottom)^2)
I would like to know if there is a way to apply a function to the whole array to avoid the expensive computation of "for loop" :)

right now my code is :

```
def set_e(self):
    pass
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, m):
            self.E[i, j] = self.get_local_e(i, j)

def get_local_e(self, i, j):
    return (
                   ((self.solution[i + 2, j + 1] - self.solution[i, j + 1]) / unt_y) ** 2
                   + ((self.solution[i + 1, j + 2] - self.solution[i + 1, j]) / unt_x) ** 2
           ) ** 0.5
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you do with cells at the edges

Comment: The cell edge are the boundary conditions in my case

Answer (score 0):

For the people that are interested in this issue, It is possible to do array calculation that way :

```
def set_e(self):
    y_tmp = np.power((self.solution[:-2, 1:-1] - self.solution[2:, 1:-1]) / unt_y, 2)
    x_tmp = np.power((self.solution[1:-1, :-2] - self.solution[1:-1, 2:]) / unt_x, 2)
    self.E = np.power(x_tmp + y_tmp, 0.5)
```

It solved my issue

Comment: This is basically just something like `np.gradient(self.solution, (unt_y, unt_x)) ** 2`

Comment: I want to use this function, but I cannot seem to be able to use your line of code, it says "TypeError: "varargs" are not valid keyword arguments." And I cannot find example online where they used at th same time the distance x and y

Comment: Please show the line you are using `np.gradient(self.solution, (unt_y, unt_x))` should work, also `np.gradient(self.solution, unt_y, unt_x)`

Comment: I tried to debug with a simple example :
`import numpy as np
print(np.gradient(np.eye(5), 1, 2))`
It seems to work to do `np.gradient(self.solution, unt_y, unt_x)` but it will give me an array with the shape (2,5,5). The simplest I can do is 
`a,b= np.gradient(np.eye(5),1,2)
c =np.power(a+b,2)`

Comment: Please please please show some working example above with a minimum example for `self.solution`. Else we don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: self.solution in my case is a np array ~ 100 * 100 which each cell is a value from ~ 0 to 1. I need to compute the gradient equation that I explained in the first post. I have a working solution which is the post related to this answer. However I feel like your way seem better and maybe more precise in the boundaries. 
I cannot send a whole array for you to try, but did you try to execute your code using the "np.eye()" function instead of my self.solution array to see if it was working ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's work on this here.
There is something strange about your equation, as only computes the gradient along one row, see `y_tmp`.
The gradient function calculates along all rows and columns, that's what the shape of the input is the same as with the output.

```
import numpy as np
solution = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
                     [3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0],
                     [5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 14.0],
                     [7.0, 11.0, 15.0, 19.0]])
unt_y = 1
unt_x = 1
g = np.gradient(solution, unt_y, unt_x) 

print(g)

a,b = g
c = np.power(a+b, 2.0)
print(c)


def set_e():
    y_tmp = np.power((solution[:-2, 1:-1] - solution[2:, 1:-1]) / unt_y, 2)
    print('y_tmp', y_tmp)
    x_tmp = np.power((solution[1:-1, :-2] - solution[1:-1, 2:]) / unt_x, 2)
    E = np.power(x_tmp + y_tmp, 0.5)
    print(E)

set_e()
```